# How do I lengthen edges in an igraph network plot (layout=fruchterman.reingold)?

Tags: networking, r, plot, igraph

Trying to do a network plot in R.
How do I lengthen edges in a network graph using IGraph?

I actually want to use the fruchterman-reingold layout.  Is there some way I can make that force-based algorithm "springier" so that my vertices are further apart?

thanks.

Comment: Any solution for that?

Answer (score 16):

You can control the Fruchterman-Reingold algorithm using the `layout.fruchterman.reingold` function. see: `help('layout.fruchterman.reingold')`. A setup that I often use and gets you a little more spacing is:

```
l <- layout.fruchterman.reingold(g,niter=500,area=vcount(g)^2.3,repulserad=vcount(g)^2.8)
plot(g,layout=l)
```

where `g` is your graph object. Best to just test different values of these parameters for your graph and see what works. Especially `repulserad` influences the spacing in a graph. The default is the square of the number of nodes, so higher values should get you more spaced graphs.

Comment: "Argument `repulserad' is deprecated and has no effect", at least in v.1.0.1 . .

Comment: Any solutions to the deprecated problem?

Answer (score 7):

If the `layout.fruchterman.reingold` algorithm still does not give what you want by tweaking the parameters, simply do the following. Every layout returns a set of coordinates, with the x- and y-coordinate in the first and second column respectively. You can apply any transformation you like here, and if you would just like to scale it, simply use

```
L = layout.fruchterman.reingold(G)*s; #Scaling factor s
```

More fancy transformations are of course also possible. Just for the record, you can also edit the layout manually with your mouse by using `tkplot(G, layout=L)`. You can get the coordinates back via `L = tkplot.getcoords(1)`.

Comment: scaling by a constant has no effect, unless you give `rescale=FALSE` parameter to the `igraph::plot` function